# Looking for Multiple Stream (per app / device) Audio Mixer App for Mac

Tags: audio, macos, volume-control

Looking for an application that allows you to cross mix all audio streams on macOS Monterey.

I have searched a great deal for something like this, but nearly everything has to do with recording, or streaming.

What I really want though is a simple way to cross-mix all audio sources such as music, with the audio from a MS Team meeting or Zoom call, for instance.

Thus far, I've had no luck.

Comment: Might give https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/whatsnew.php a try. Somehow, never came across it before.

Answer (score 0):

After testing SoundSource by Rogue Amoeba for about a month - I believe it to be the solution (or the best I have found yet).

https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/

It is not a free application, but for my use case, it was well worth the cost.

I can:

- mix and balance specific audio streams on an app by app basis
- modify specific input and output device sound

The latter is helpful for switching between I/O devices such as earbud out and in, vs earbud out and boom-mic in, etc. This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.

Here is what the expanded controls look like in a typical case:

[image: What SoundSource looks like in my use]

Performance: Obviously, I can't give specifics, but 2019 Macbook Pro, running OS 12.4 -> I have not noticed any serious resource drains. If I have run into any problems, it has mainly revolved around a specific app or device connecting incorrectly, or audio being accidentally muted.